# How to get the current url of each page in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to implement  copy to clipboard function to set the current url of each page ,
I have followed the Gatsby docs : [gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/)

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
const Page = ({ location, data }) => {
  const canonicalUrl = data.site.siteMetadata.siteURL + location.pathname
  return <div>The URL of this page is {canonicalUrl}</div>
}
export default Page
export const query = graphql`
  query PageQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        siteURL
      }
    }
  }
`
```

eventually I get an error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the lifecycle of the requested page (`Page`) `location` may not be defined, hence `pathname` breaks.

Try adding a default value or optional chaining like:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
const Page = ({ location={}, data }) => {
  const canonicalUrl = data.site.siteMetadata.siteURL + location?.pathname
  return <div>The URL of this page is {canonicalUrl}</div>
}
export default Page
export const query = graphql`
  query PageQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        siteURL
      }
    }
  }
`
```